# I want to put pagination on my page in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I want to put pagination on my view page of matrimonial project . 
In this project flow of variables pass in this way i.e from  View-page(search form)- to - controller -to- model -to- view page...What i did is i passed values from view-controller-model-view.
In result page(i.e in view page) I'm able to get total number of records and total number of pages and also able to get individual values of each record.

Here starts my question now i want to add pagination on result page (i.e view page)
I'm posting controller, model, and view page.

**CONTROLLER PAGE**

```
$per_page=$this->input->post('per_page');
$look = $this->input->post('look');
$age = $this->input->post('age'); 
$age_from = $this->input->post('age_from');
$age_to = $this->input->post('age_to');
$se_ct = $this->input->post('sect');
$subsect = $this->input->post('subsect');
$coun_try = $this->input->post('country');
$sta_te = $this->input->post('state');
$ci_ty = $this->input->post('city');
$qualification = $this->input->post('qualification');

$data['showdata']   =   $this->searchresultss->login($per_page,$look,$age, $age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try,$sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification);

$this->load->view('searchresult',$data);
```

**MODEL PAGE**

```
 function login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification)
 {
$query="SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE  

if('$se_ct'!='',sect =  '$se_ct' AND if('$subsect' !='',subsect =  '$subsect',subsect like  '%%'),sect like  '%%' AND subsect like  '%%')
AND
IF( '$coun_try' !='', country =  '$coun_try'
AND 
if('$sta_te' !='', state =  '$sta_te'
AND  
if('$ci_ty' !='',city =  '$ci_ty',city like  '%%'),state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%'), country LIKE  '%%'
AND state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%' ) 
AND age >=  '$age_from'
AND age <=  '$age_to'
AND 
IF('$qualification' !='',qualification =  '$qualification',  qualification LIKE  '%%' ) 
And gender = '$look'
And status='1'";
$data=array();
$query=$this->db->query($query);
$data['results']=$query->result_array();
$data['count']=$query->num_rows();

$data['pages']=ceil($data['count']/3);

return $data;
 }
}
```

**MY VIEW PAGE(I.E.RESULT PAGE)**

```
<?php
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r($showdata);
if (isset($showdata)){
            foreach ($showdata['results'] as $k => $v) {
                ?>
                <table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>  <?php echo $v['gender'];?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $v['email'];?></td>
  </tr>

</table>



   <?php
            }
        }
        echo $showdata['count'];  echo $showdata['pages'];
        ?>
```

`What i tried to do in above script is  to get query result  along with number of records and number of pages through which i thought i can do pagination work but i was wrong.  so please ci developers help me out in writing pagination script. I am completely new to Ci framework.

Comment: Are you using Codeigniter's pagination library or are you wanting to build your own?

Comment: I'd highly recomend trying to use using CI's paginatin library before writing your own! =]

Comment: what you want me to do

Comment: I am completely new so thinking in what way to go

Comment: what ever you suggest to follow i will follow

Answer (score 0):

use ci pagination library e.g.

controller

```
 $config = array();
            $config["base_url"] = url;
            $config["total_rows"] = query;
            $config["per_page"] = 5;
            $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
            $config["first_link"] = 'First';
            $config["last_link"] = 'Last';
            $config["prev_link"] = 'Previous';
            $config["next_link"] = 'Next';
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;

            $this->db->limit($config["per_page"], $page);
$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

view:

display links on view

Comment: model is not necessary always, u can also do without model

Comment: can you explain clearly what i changes i  need to do in model controller and in my view

Comment: include $this->load->library("pagination"); your r taking query result from model instead you can right query in controller itself

Comment: so what you want me to do i am new

Comment: just add code in controller where
$config['total_rows']=query is count of result rows
and show $links in view

Answer (score 0):

```
    If you want use CI pagination below code help for you

    public function paginationFunction($pg = 0)                     
    {

       $query="SELECT *
               FROM users
               WHERE  
              if('$se_ct'!='',sect =  '$se_ct' AND if('$subsect' !='',subsect =  '$subsect',subsect like  '%%'),sect like  '%%' AND subsect like  '%%')
    AND
    IF( '$coun_try' !='', country =  '$coun_try'
    AND 
    if('$sta_te' !='', state =  '$sta_te'
    AND  
    if('$ci_ty' !='',city =  '$ci_ty',city like  '%%'),state LIKE  '%%'
    AND city LIKE  '%%'), country LIKE  '%%'
    AND state LIKE  '%%'
    AND city LIKE  '%%' ) 
    AND age >=  '$age_from'
    AND age <=  '$age_to'
    AND 
    IF('$qualification' !='',qualification =  '$qualification',  qualification LIKE  '%%' ) 
    And gender = '$look'
    And status='1'";

    $data=array();   
    $query=$this->db->query($query)->result_array();
    $totalRecord=$query->num_rows();

             /* [Start:: Pagination code] */

            $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'test'; //page url i.e.controller name 
            $data['count'] = $totalRecord;
            $config['total_rows'] = $totalRecord;
            $config['per_page'] = 2;  //per page records
            $config['cur_page'] = $pg;  //third parameter first time is 0 
            $config['num_links'] = 4;

            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><strong><a class="active" href="javascript:void(0);">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></strong></li>';
            $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul>';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data["pageLinks"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $data['page'] = $pg;

            //run same query but add limit 
           $query="SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE  

if('$se_ct'!='',sect =  '$se_ct' AND if('$subsect' !='',subsect =  '$subsect',subsect like  '%%'),sect like  '%%' AND subsect like  '%%')
AND
IF( '$coun_try' !='', country =  '$coun_try'
AND 
if('$sta_te' !='', state =  '$sta_te'
AND  
if('$ci_ty' !='',city =  '$ci_ty',city like  '%%'),state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%'), country LIKE  '%%'
AND state LIKE  '%%'
AND city LIKE  '%%' ) 
AND age >=  '$age_from'
AND age <=  '$age_to'
AND 
IF('$qualification' !='',qualification =  '$qualification',  qualification LIKE  '%%' ) 
And gender = '$look'
And status='1' limit $pg,$config['per_page']"; 

            $data['results']=$query->result_array();
```

}

Comment: patil need so clarity ru there